# CSS behaving differently in identical pages

Tags: css, drupal

everything is the same on these pages except the url, they are pulled from the same template file in Drupal.

[nyc.thedelimagazine.com/snacks](http://nyc.thedelimagazine.com/snacks)
http://newengland.thedelimagazine.com/snacks/2011

in my document head I have a style rule

```
a:link, a:visited {
font-size: 12px;
}
```

overriding a stylesheet that comes earlier in the cascade.

/sites/upload-files/css/73b0e63963a93c9193db836f27e20f89.css

The font is way too big, the CSS override works in the first link but not the second. The font I am referring to is only visible after you vote in the poll and reload the page.  "See full results | About"

By the way I also can't edit this linked CSS file via FTP because Owner/Group is set to "apache" rather than my user name. Which is why I need the override.

Comment: It looks ok to me in firefox 3.6.

Comment: A tool like Firebug will very quickly tell you what styles are affecting an element and what files they're in.

Comment: I can't see any difference between them to be honest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two pages are not identical.  In the one which is working, the text is nested within a `td` with a class of `soups`.  The one which is not working is not.  Since your css rule relies on the `soups` class, this rule is not applied.

EDIT:  To be more clear, the rule that you have in your question is not the one which is making the text smaller in the first link.  The rule is:

```
.soups a, .soups font{
```

And is actually 14px and not 12.

Comment: i have a global rule to target all links a:link and a:visited